# How to split with the Number and Add the Text before and after the number in Js or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Multiple Number with comma separate. I need to split with comma and add the text before the number as well as after the number.

```
Input:-  x = "2254,1234";
Output:- x = abc2254def or abc1234def
```

I want above output. please help me

Comment: is your input an array of numbers ?

Comment: Use `.map()` to add the letters around each number, and `.join()` to join them together with `or` between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to separate your input, then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to perform a function on each of the items found in the split string. We then use [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) to concatenate our strings, and [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to make sure that the input doesnt have any unexpected spaces in it. We then finally [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to return a single string.

Let's not forget to add some sanity checking in the function, so we'll check the [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) for the supplied numberString, and short circuit if it's not a string.

```
/*
 * Helper function for logging an array of numbers, prefixed and suffixed with supplied string
 * @param {String} prefix The string to append to the beginning of the output
 * @param {String} suffix The string to append to the end of the output
 * @param {String} divider The string that separates each output value
 * @param {String} numberString The string of numbers, separated with commas to iterate through
 * @returns {String} The concatenated string
 */
var convertNumbers = function(prefix, suffix, divider, numberString){
    // short circuit if numberString is NOT a string
    if(typeof numberString !== 'string') return;
    return numberString.split(',').map(function(number){
        return '' + prefix + number.trim() + suffix;
    }).join(divider);
}
```

This function, returns the string, so would be called using something like:

`console.log( convertNumbers('abc', 'def', ' or ', "1,2,3,4,5, 6,7 ,8") );`

You can replace the 4th parameter with your `input.value` based upon your html.

**NOTE**

Although above is a more readable solution (and this is clearly not Golf), you could simply `split` using a regex and `join`

```
var convertNumbers = function(prefix, suffix, divider, numberString){
    // short circuit if numberString is NOT a string
    if(typeof numberString !== 'string') return;
    return '' + prefix + (numberString.split(/[\s,]+/).join(suffix + divider + prefix)) + suffix;
}
```

Comment: i have input field <input id="test" type="textbox" value ="2254,2212,3567,4266"/> So how can

numberArray = test.value;

is not working

Comment: How to Add the "or" only after First Set of Number ?

Comment: abc2254efg or abc1234efg and if the input is 3 set of numbers abc2254efg or abc1234efg or abc****efg?

Answer (score 1):

```
  var y = "2254,1234";    
  var x = y.split(',');
  for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    var pre = 'abc';
    var post = 'def';
    var result = pre+x[i]+post;
    console.log(result);
  }
```

Comment: Its not a array. only the numbers. Dynamically inserted after some function

Answer (score 1):

You just need to split you input by using `split()` function then then go through loop and add before and after text to every element.

```js
x = "2254,1234";
var y = x.split(",");
$.each(y,function(i,e){
  if(y.length == 1)
    {
      var str = "abc"+e+"xyz";
      alert(str)
    }else{
       var str = "abc"+e+"efg";
       alert(str)
      }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How to Add the "or"  only after First Set of Number ?

Comment: abc2254efg or abc1234efg and if the input is 3 set of numbers  abc2254efg or abc1234efg or abc****efg?

Comment: @Crock you mean if number is in single set then abc2254def else abc2254efg correct me if i am wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe Helpful, Try this.

```js
//$InputValue = "2254,1234,3345";
$InputValue = "2254,3345";

$Res = WrapString($InputValue);
console.log($Res);


function WrapString($inputString){ $result = [];
  $inputString = $inputString.split(",");
  
  for($i=0;$i<$inputString.length;$i++){                                    
    $result.push(GenrateRandString(3)+$inputString[$i]+GenrateRandString(3));
  }
  return $result;
}

function GenrateRandString($length) {
    $text = "";
    $possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for(var i = 0; i < $length; i++) {
        $text += $possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * $possible.length));
    }
    return $text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```